# Converting template classes with Dozer

Tags: dozer

Consider below classes. How do I convert class A to B using Dozer without using custom converters?

```
interface IProperty<T> {
  T getValue();
  String getNilReason();
....
}

class Property<T> implements IProperty<T> {
  T value;
  String nilReasons();
  ...setters and geters 
}

class X1 {
 String a;
}

class X2 {
 String a;
}

class A {
 IProperty<X1> x1;
}

class B {
 X2 x2;
}
```

Can someone provide a Dozer mapping XML for above classes?

Answer (score 0):

I did a code review of Dozer and as far as I understood it doesn't support custom generics, but just the Java collection generics.

I'm thinking that I will take a stab and implement the support I need in Dozer by myself.